# Is there a way to get only the commits on a specific branch from the BitBucket server REST API?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I'm using the following call to the BitBucket 1.0 API to get all the commits on a branch. This call returns all the commits from the specific branch, but also all the commits from the beginning of time. I'm looking for a way to only get the commits that were committed to the specified branch.  Is this even possible?

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{ProjectKey}/repos/{RepoSlug}/commits?until={branchId}
```

I'm looking for a way to only get the commits since the branch split from the 'tree', to the tip of the branch.  It doesn't appear that there's any data in the response that I can use to determine which commit was the first on the branch, or last on the 'tree'

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. A branch is the tip of a tree that extends back to the first commit in the repository. If you ask for "all the commits in a branch", you're going to get exactly what you've described.

Comment: @larsks Yes, I understand that.  What I'm looking for is a way to limit the number of commits to the point where the branch split from the tree.  I know there are ways to do this with git log, so I'm just curious if anybody knows how to do it through the BitBucket API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the branch that the branch in question branched from, you can use the /compare/commits endpoint to get the commits that are on the specified branch but not the 'base' branch.

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{ProjectKey}/repos/{RepoSlug}/compare/commits?from={BranchId}&to={BaseBranchId}
```

For example:

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{ProjectKey}/repos/{RepoSlug}/compare/commits?from=feature%2FmyCoolFeature&to=master
```

This will give a list of all the commits that exist on the feature/myCoolFeature branch, but not the master branch.

For my specific scenario, this is enough to get me by.  If you're in a situation where you don't know where the branch in question branched from, I haven't yet found a good workaround for that situation.